# TikZ nested foreach for staggered rectangular grid

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use TikZ to produce a staggered rectangular grid in LaTeX: (x,y) with 1<=y<=5 and y<=x<=y+5, say.  I have tried the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y in {1,...,5} {
\foreach \x in {\y, ...,10} {
%%\if (\x <= \y+5) 
\draw (\x,-\y) +(-.5,-.5) rectangle ++(.5,.5);
\draw (\x,-\y) node{$a_{\x}^{\y}$};
%%\fi
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And this gets me the staggered start.  However, if I change the limit of "10" in the second foreach to "\y+5", I get an error "! Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)."  If, instead of that, I remove the comment marks and apply an if test, then the diagram is empty.  (If I try a simpler "\if \x < 8", I get the column for x==11, which I do not understand.)

I can easily believe that I haven't got the syntax right -- this is my first attempt at anything in TikZ.  So, as well as the simple fix, I would appreciate some meta-advice: How do I debug this? Can you recommend an alternative package where I would not struggle to do such a simple thing?  Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You cannot do computations in the argument of `\foreach`. Just do `\pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xmax}{\y+5}` and then replace `10` by `\xmax`. And you need to work with `\ifnum` instead of `\if`, which works for integers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two reasons why your attempt did not quite give you what you want:

1. You cannot do computations in the argument of `\foreach`.
2. The `\if` clause does not work like that. Since these are integers, you could have worked with `\ifnum`, something like `\ifnum\x<8` or so.

Here is a version that does what I think you want to do.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y as \xmax using {int(\y+5)}] in {1,...,5} {
\foreach \x in {\y, ...,\xmax} {
\draw (\x,-\y) +(-.5,-.5) rectangle ++(.5,.5);
\draw (\x,-\y) node{$a_{\x}^{\y}$};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really cool. Although it's an old question, can anyone give some intuition to the code? I'd like to do something like this with larger cells and with distinct text in each of the cells, but don't really understand the code.

Comment: is is possible to fill a matrix using this code?